# How to make dropdown animation on hover in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncrzcqrj/1/) link. In hover animation works(fadeIn), but when cursor is out, where is no animation(fadeOut). Any ideas? Thanks

```
  $('ul.navbar-nav > li.dropdown').hover(
    function(){
      $('li.dropdown > ul').removeClass('fadeOut')
      $('li.dropdown > ul').addClass('fadeIn')
    },

    function(){
      $('li.dropdown > ul').addClass('fadeOut')
      $('li.dropdown > ul').removeClass('fadeIn')
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using the fadeIn / fadeOut jQuery methods, and adding and removing the open class:

```
$('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown').hover(
    function() {
      $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
      $(this).addClass('open');
    }, function() {   
      $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
      $(this).removeClass('open');
    }
);
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/ncrzcqrj/3/).